# react-native-elements checkbox shows 'undefined is not an object (evaluating '_this.setState')

Tags: react-native, expo, react-native-elements

I haven't been able to find anything specific to fixing React-Native-Checkbox, everything I can find refers to an error in someones `this.function();` setup.

Code:

```
<RNElements.CheckBox
  center
  title='Click Here'
  onPress={() => this.setState({checked: !this.state.checked})}
/>
```

Error:

```
TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating '_this.setState')
```

I understand that it doesn't know what to use setState on, but I'm not sure how to resolve it. Any ideas?